# Can a Matlab GUI (created in Guide) appear in or in front of a Psychtoolbox window?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, psychtoolbox

I'm using psychtoolbox 3 with Matlab 2019b on a Mac running OSX 10.12.

I'm presenting static image stimuli using psychtoolbox (PTB) and would like to have a floating audio player gui object that I created using guide to appear on the screen as well. Importantly, the audio player has its own functions (slider bar to fastFWD and rewind the audio and a play/pause button) and I need to preserve the button's functionality. Rather than attempting to recreate the  the player and buttons etc. within PTB, is it possible to display the gui above the window's screen content?

I've seen other threads about displaying a figure within a PTB window, but this was for graph rather than a gui. I don't believe PTB retains the functionality of the buttons when displaying the figure. I've also considered making the window smaller than the full screen in order to display the figure on the side, but I'd prefer to remain full screen if at all possible.

So to summarize, is there a way for a figure window appear in front of the PTB window? Alternatively, can a PTB window appear within a figure window (i.e., within the axes of a gui created in guide?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe what you want - to have a full screen Psychtoolbox window as well as a MATLAB GUI .fig as an overlay - is possible. Even if the Psychtoolbox window is less than full screen, you can't give the MATLAB .fig focus and have it overlay the Psychtoolbox window, it will be placed underneath the Psychtoolbox window. You also won't be able to plot the Psychtoolbox window inside of a MATLAB GUI window. What I think your options are:

1. Make the Psychtoolbox window less than full screen, place the player GUI next to it.
2. Use a secondary monitor to host the MATLAB GUI, so the Psychtoolbox screen can be full size on the main monitor.

Comment: I appreciate your time in responding.  While using the gui would be great, recreating the player functionality in PTB seems relatively straightforward, so I guess I'll go that route.  Thanks for your help!